# Launching a specific simulator in irb using Calabash iOS

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, irb, calabash, calabash-ios

I am using Calabash for iOS testing and when I go into `calabash-ios console`, open the irb and enter `start_test_server_in_background` it launches the simulator. The problem that I am having is its building a simulator that I don't want to work with anymore. I started using the 5s simulator, but now I want it to build the 6s when i enter `start_test_server_in_background`.

Is there an environmental variable that needs to be set or one I can pass in a variable in the console while entering `start_test_server_in_background`?

Answer (score 3):

When you start the console you can specify DEVICE_TARGET in the same way as when you run tests. Just place it in front of the call to start the console:

```
DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (7.1 Simulator)' calabash-ios console
```

Comment: Thanks, you da man! I tried that after I launched the irb. Didn't know you can pass params before launching the console. Makes since thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you're going to use the console, then your `cal-scheme` needs to match which simulator you want to use so you would have to create and build a new scheme with that simulator.

However, if you want to run your test script, then you can use the terminal command `instruments -s` to get a list of your simulators.  Using this method, your new command to run the test script will look like this:
`cucumber DEVICE_TARGET="iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)" features/your_script.feature`

Hope this helps you.